# Move semantics to take ownership of data from a buffer?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I currently deal with some data recording, using a buffer, i.e. during the recording, data is stored in a `map`, and when the recording ends, this map is used to build a `CaptureRecord` which is pushed onto a global record (of type `std::vector<CaptureRecord>`) which stores every record done so far.

The code for this last part looks like this:

```
void CaptureRecorder::stopDataRecording()
{
    OutputDebugString(L"Stopping data recording\n");
    //Omitted stuff

    //The CaptureRecord ctor takes a map as parameter
    m_globalRecord.emplace_back(m_currentCaptureElements);
    m_currentCaptureElements.clear();

    //Omitted stuff
}
```

The problem is that if these two lines seems to take a bit of time (up to seconds), time that increases proportionnally to the size of the record (which makes it quite obvious to me that the copy is at fault here).

So what I'd like to do is that when creating the `CaptureRecord` through the `emplace_back()`, it takes ownership of the date contained in `m_currentCaptureElement`. Thing is, I don't really know how to do that. I tried with move semantics, i.e. with `std::move()` for the argument of emplace_back(), along with the following code for the ctor of `CaptureRecord` :

```
CaptureRecord(std::map<int, ProcessedCaptElem> record):
    recordContent(std::move(record))
{
    for(auto& recordElement : recordContent){
        m_timestamps.emplace_back(recordElement.second.timestamp);
        m_intensities.emplace_back(recordElement.second.calculatedIntensity);
    }
}
```

but it didn't seem to have any effect (which leads me to believe it still "can't" move from the variable `m_currentCaptureElements`).

So my question(s)is:

Is it possible to do something like this (move from some sort of buffer, then resetting it) and how ?

**Note:** I'm completely open to suggestions that don't involve move semantics. These were the closest I could think of for passing the data around without copying it, but there might be other solutions that I may have missed that don't involve moves.

Comment: Do you really need to store both the map and copies of timestamps, calculated intensities etc. separately? Seems like you should be able to fetch these from the map itself as needed.

Comment: I believe you need a constructor for `CaptureRecord` that takes `map<...>&&`, then call `m_globalRecord.emplace_back(move(m_currentCaptureElements));`

Comment: since you store the entire record in CaptueRecord, can't get rid of m_globalRecord and instead add an item to the global before you start recording, and fill that new item directly? - apart from that, if you expect m_currentCaptureElements to be moved from, isn't it UB to call clear() on it afterwards?

Comment: Shouldn't you also be passing `std::map<int ProcessedCaptElem>` by reference rather than by value as you are at the moment. This will be meaning it's copied before you even do the move currently.

Comment: @All: Yeah the two vectors are probably overkill there, I should reconsider that.

Comment: @Choc13 Well, I based my ctor on an example I found in a SO answer (I'd like to find it again), where the person passed its arguments by value, and used `std::move(arg)` in the initialization list...

Comment: @stijn You're right, that would be an idea to explore as well (though I think it won't fit easily without redesigning a good part of my program, but well, if that results in much clearer and efficient code, I see no reason not to go on with that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you want to transfer the contents of `m_currentCaptureElements` to another object. So you need to `move` it.

```
m_globalRecord.emplace_back(std::move(m_currentCaptureElements));
m_currentCaptureElements.clear();
```

Now, to take advantage of the rvalue map that is being given to the `CaptureRecord` constructor, you need a constructor overload that takes an rvalue reference to the map.

```
CaptureRecord(std::map<int, ProcessedCaptElem>&& record):
    recordContent(std::move(record))
{
    // ...
}
```

If you need to separately store copies of the timestamps and calculated intensities outside of the map, you can't move items from the map, assuming you want to keep a copy of the map around as well. If you don't really need the map, you can change the constructor to

```
CaptureRecord(std::map<int, ProcessedCaptElem>&& record)
{
    for(auto&& recordElement : record){
        m_timestamps.emplace_back(std::move(recordElement.second.timestamp));
        m_intensities.emplace_back(std::move(recordElement.second.calculatedIntensity));
    }
}
```

Assuming you need an overload that takes lvalues also, you can create another constructor that copies items out of the map.

```
CaptureRecord(std::map<int, ProcessedCaptElem> const& record)
   recordContent(record)
{
    for(auto const& recordElement : recordContent){
        m_timestamps.push_back(recordElement.second.timestamp);
        m_intensities.push_back(recordElement.second.calculatedIntensity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and especially the way you present it that makes me understand, at least partly, the thinking process I should use when using move semantics. I'll have to worry about the Rule of Five now, I suppose, but I can do my research on that :)

Comment: @JBL Regarding the Rule of Five, unless you're writing a resource owning RAII object, you should be trying to follow the [Rule of Zero](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html) instead. IOW, your classes should be composed of standalone objects that manage individual resources, if needed. That way you don't need to worry about the Rule of Three/Five, let the compiler figure all that out for you. Unfortunately, this is not currently possible with MSVC since that compiler will not automatically generate move constructor/assignment op (or both, don't remember exactly).

Comment: The Rule Of Zero was exactly what I had in mind, though the fact I'm writing a custom move constructor of sorts led me to think about this rule. But, oh well, if Visual won't let me write a move ctor only...

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear to me what some of the types you're dealing with are, and how some things are structured. But from what I can gather, your `CaptureRecord` constructor is almost right. What you're missing it more `std::move`s...

```
m_timestamps.emplace_back(std::move(recordElement.second.timestamp));
m_intensities.emplace_back(std::move(recordElement.second.calculatedIntensity));
```

Also, you could `reserve` `m_timestamps` and `m_intensities`. That might help performance a lot. You'll also have to construct `CaptureRecord` by `std::move`ing it a map...

```
CaptureRecord cap(std::move(myMap));
```

Use `std::move` *everywhere* you mean to move ownership from one place to another. Also to note is that any object you are `std::move`ing must have a move constructor/move assignment operator. If you're using VS, it will not generate them for you like it does for copy constructors/copy assignment operators. It should. It doesn't. You'll have to do it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! The last bit about VS not doing this is actually really valuable, I might have ended up running into this problem in the future, that'll save me some research.